# Rmarkdown hangs when using knit_child

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I have an Rmarkdown code to generate a report for multiple parameters. Therefore I am using the `knit_child` function in a loop where the first iteration runs fine but then it hangs infinitely and never begins a second iteration.

On my desktop (Ubuntu 18.04) the code works fine and the pdf report is generated but on our server (CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)) the mentioned problem appears. Based on some research I tried to update pandoc (to version 2.7.2) but the problem persists. There is no difference if I run my scripts from the command line or RStudio.

```
for (spec in params$species) {
    out = tryCatch(c(out, knit_child('child.Rmd')), error = function(e) e)
    if (inherits(out, "error")) {
      next
    }
  }
```

There are no errors, the script just does not move on to the next iteration. If I only provide one `species` the pdf is generated but not if I want to loop through multiple.